# Old Flink checkpoints not always correctly deleted

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-checkpoint

### Summary

We are using Flink 1.15.1 and have long-running stateful Flink jobs ingesting data from Kafka topics. They are configured to write checkpoints, with a RocksDB backend on S3.

We have noticed that sometimes the S3 "folders" for some checkpoints were getting very large and increasing continuously. They are also larger than what Flink reports in the UI. When cancelling the associated Flink jobs, some files are deleted but not all of them.

This seems to happen especially when Flink struggles to complete the checkpoints in the first time.

### Experiment

I tried to reproduce the problem by submitting a job with a very small checkpointing timeout and a continuous input data:

- Initially, the checkpoints were successful, new `chk-<checkpoint id>` folders were created, and regularly replaced the previous one. So, at one point in time, I had one `chk-<id>` folder with a `_metadata` file and two other files. Those two other files had sizes that kept increasing as the job consumed more and more data.
- At some point, the checkpoints started to time out, as expected. As I kept the job running like this for a while, I noticed that some older `chk-<id>` folders were not removed, even though there were more recent `chk-<id>` folders. Those folders were not empty. However, the only `_metadata` file I found does not reference them, while it does reference other checkpoint files from the same folder. So they look like uncollected garbage.
- I stopped the data source. The job started writing checkpoints successfully again, but the old uncollected files were still there.
- I removed some of the files that I thought were garbage, and the job kept running without complaining.
- I cencelled the job. The `chk-<id>` folder that seemed valid was deleted. But the remaining `chk-<id>` folders that seemed problematic were indeed still present.

Any idea what could be the problem here? How to force Flink to remove files that are not part of its checkpoints anymore?

Comment: When the checkpoints timed out, did the job fail, or was it configured to tolerate the timeouts and continue running?

Comment: I think the job restarted.

Comment: Old pending checkpoints will be cancelled if checkpoint it not completed in configured timeout period. The job should keep running if checkpoint is timeout.

Comment: Checkpoint files(for completed checkpoints and aborted checkpoints) are not guaranteed to be deleted by Flink job. You can check logs from flink master by searching keywords like: `Executing discard procedure for` OR `Could not properly dispose the private states in the pending checkpoint`

Comment: Well that's annoying, because we get gigabytes of useless data and we don't know what we can delete manually until the whole job has to be cancelled. I could not find the logs you suggest but did find `Could not properly discard new sst file states.` logs.

Comment: The Flink community is aware of that issue and there's [FLIP-270](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-270%3A+Repeatable+Cleanup+of+Checkpoints) covering it. The discussion on the problem hasn't proceeded, yet, because we still have to run some experiments before coming up with a proper solution here.